# react-native-webview giving RNCWebview error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

React Native Webview module is giving the following error irrespective you do `react-native run-ios` or start the app using XCode.

`requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManage`

Answer (score 1):

Try `react-native link package_name` and then `cd ios` and `pod install` 
This should solve the problem